# Refrescar formulario al actualizar con AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Tengo un formulario que al hacerle submit quiero que se refresquen los campos sin necesidad de actualizar.

```
<form id="actulizaInfo" method="post" autocomplete="off">
   @csrf
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
         <label for="nombre" class="labelFormEditCuenta">Nombre<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form_pedido" id="nombre" value="{{ $cliente->name }}" required>
      </div>
    </div>
     ....
</form>
```

El AJAX

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $('#actulizaInfo').submit(function (evento) {
        evento.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("actulizaInfo"));
        //formData.append("dato", "valor");
        
        
          $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            url: "{{ url('guardar_info_cliente') }}",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
    
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#btninfo_clie').html('<img src="{{ asset('images/gif/migif.gif')}}" class="loader"> Guardando...');
            },
            success: function (resultado){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //$(".infoClieAct").load(location.href + " .infoClieAct");
                    toastr["success"]("Cambios guardados", "Mensaje");
                    
                    $('#btninfo_clie').html('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Guardar cambios');
                    $f.closest('form').get(0).reset();
                }, 2300);
            }
          });
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Parece que lo hace bien, pero me devuelve este error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined

Según los ejemplos que he seguido esa `$f` tendria que ser `$this` pero si le pongo esto me refresca el formulario al punto antes de guardarse.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres, tu dices `pero si le pongo esto me refresca el formulario al punto antes de guardarse.`, pero si no le colocas el reset te deja los valores exactamente igual que al momento de guardar...entonces cual es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que funciona bien, pero me marca ese error la consola, y me hace pensar que algo no está bien

Comment: Te funciona bien por que esa línea es inútil y debes borrarla (porque de lo que entiendo, tu no quieres resetear el form). El error es porque `$f` no existe, y si quisieras resetear el form simplemente haces `document.getElementById('actulizaInfo').reset()`

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se refresque con los valores recien guardados, claro ahora comprendo lo que dices, al no hacer nada se queda tal como está pero guardando en la BD :S

Comment: https://www.memesmonkey.com/images/memesmonkey/17/17d743c3511ae1992e48e409b1fad0b8.jpeg